# Other users seem to lose AuthTicket when a single user logs out

Tags: .net, forms-authentication

We are running a .NET 2.0 Web Application.  One of our clients is experiencing an issue where, when two different users are logged into out application on two different machines and one logs out the other user seems to lose its AuthTicket (none of the content is displayed and the page just looks broken).  They must log out and log back in again in order to continue using the application.  As you can image, this is very frustrating to them and they want answers ASAP.

We recreated their setup in our lab and attempted to reproduce the issue but we cannot.  Also, this issue has been seen on other sites but has "fixed itself" at some point, though no one can seem to explain how.

This seems like some sort of configuration issue to me, especially when we can run the same version with the same hardware and don't see it.  However, the testing and research I have done thus far has yielded NOTHING.  The only semi useful information was to check to see if the AppPools are set to recycle if using too much memory or something.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here is the web.config entry for authentication if this helps:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".EyeQCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30"   path="/" slidingExpiration="true">
    </forms>
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was no with AuthTickets, though it was behaving exactly as if it was.  The issue was with cache and how we use/store the values (more specifically skinning --> we are a tad behind the times).